# PhpStorm - search for translatable strings through the project

Tags: phpstorm

Is it possible to easily search for all translatable strings in the Angular project in PhpStorm? PhpStorm knows what those strings are as they're marked with a different color, so it must be searchable in some way.

Maybe some devilish regex in Find in Files popup?

[image: Screenshot from PhpStorm]

Comment: *"PhpStorm knows what those strings are as they're marked with a different color"* TBH I do not see that they are highlighted in a some special color. I see 3 candidates on your screenshot: "How it works", "Close click" and "Close" -- 1 is a plain text in HTML context and 2 are inside attribute values. All of them seem to use standard colors for such elements (that the Theme defines)...

Comment: Anyway: check **i18n Ally** plugin (it helps extracting translatable strings into special files and replace original place with appropriate code), maybe it can be of any help here. It works in PHP/JS/Blade files so maybe it can work with Angular as well. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/17212-i18n-ally